# How to create password protect zip file in nodejs using node-7z-archive package

Tags: node.js, file, zip, unzip, 7zip

Please anyone guide me, how We can create password protected zip file and extract.
using node-7z-archive https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-7z-archive
actually I want to create password protect zip file with a folder

code to create a simple zip file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const archiver = require('archiver');

const sourceFolder = 'create_zip'; // Replace with the actual folder path
const zipFileName = 'output.zip';

// Create a writable stream to the zip file
const output = fs.createWriteStream(zipFileName);

// Create a zip archive
const archive = archiver('zip', {
  zlib: { level: 9 } // Sets the compression level
});

// Pipe the archive to the output stream
archive.pipe(output);

// Add the entire folder to the archive
archive.directory(sourceFolder, false); // 'false' means no root directory in archive

// Finalize the archive
archive.finalize();

// Wait for the output stream to finish writing
output.on('close', () => {
  console.log('Zip archive created.');
});

// Handle errors during archiving
archive.on('error', (err) => {
  throw err;
});
```

please help me, How to create password protect zip file in nodejs using node-7z-archive package.

Comment: https://github.com/quentinrossetti/node-7z/issues/63

Comment: Thanks,How to get seven package, const myStream = Seven.add('Files.7z', '*.txt', {
    recursive: true,
    password: 'super duper secret!'
})
how to install seven package

Comment: I tried with this 'npm i seven' command  but its not working,getting error:


node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:356
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'E:\design\uploadwithnodejs\node_modules\seven\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

Comment: Read `https://github.com/quentinrossetti/node-7z/
README.md` , Installation: `npm install --save node-7z`

Comment: I have one more error 

"<Error: spawn 7z ENOENT>"

Comment: my code:
import Seven from 'node-7z'
const myStream = Seven.add('Files.7z', '*.txt', {
    recursive: true,
    password: 'super duper secret!'
})
// Handle progress events (optional)
myStream.on('progress', (event) => {
  console.log(`Progress: ${event.percent}%`);
});

// Handle completion
myStream.on('end', () => {
  console.log('7-Zip archive created with password.');
});

// Handle errors
myStream.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
});

Comment: please check my code,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working code, but make sure download:7z https://www.7-zip.org/download.html as per system(window,mac,or any other) and setup environment

```html
<pre>
import  Seven from 'node-7z'
const options = {
  // Replace 'your-password' with the desired password for the archive.
  password: '1234',
};

const filesToCompress = 'create_zip'; // List of files to include in the archive.

const archiveName = 'myArchive.7z'; // Specify the name of the archive file.

// Create the 7z archive with a password.
const myStream = Seven.add(archiveName, filesToCompress, options);

// Handle progress events (optional)
myStream.on('progress', (event) => {
  console.log(`Progress: ${event.percent}%`);
});

// Handle completion
myStream.on('end', () => {
  console.log('7-Zip archive created with password.');
});

// Handle errors
myStream.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
});

</pre>
```